# java regexp for reluctant matching

Tags: java, regex, reluctant-quantifiers

need to find an expression for the following problem:

```
String given = "{ \"questionID\" :\"4\", \"question\":\"What is your favourite hobby?\",\"answer\" :\"answer 4\"},{ \"questionID\" :\"5\", \"question\" :\"What was the name of the first company you worked at?\",\"answer\" :\"answer 5\"}";
```

What I want to get: `"{ \"questionID\" :\"4\", \"question\":\"What is your favourite hobby?\",\"answer\" :\"*******\"},{ \"questionID\" :\"5\", \"question\" :\"What was the name of the first company you worked at?\",\"answer\" :\"******\"}";`

What I am trying:

```
    String regex = "(.*answer\"\\s:\"){1}(.*)(\"[\\s}]?)";
    String rep = "$1*****$3";
    System.out.println(test.replaceAll(regex, rep));
```

What I am getting:

```
"{ \"questionID\" :\"4\", \"question\":\"What is your favourite hobby?\",\"answer\" :\"answer 4\"},{ \"questionID\" :\"5\", \"question\" :\"What was the name of the first company you worked at?\",\"answer\" :\"******\"}";
```

Because of the greedy behaviour, the first group catches both "answer" parts, whereas I want it to stop after finding enough, perform replacement, and then keep looking further.

Comment: I don't get the question. Have you *looked* at the Java `Pattern` class?

Comment: I can't test right now but you can try `(\"answer\"\\s*:\\s*\")(.*?)(\")`

Comment: I did sir, I believe replaceAll will use Pattern.compile internally. Basically the problem is somewhere in my regexp - I need it to replace ALL occurences of text between "answer " and " }", but because of its greediness, it grabs more than I want. Ie. in my "given" String, I want characters 87 to 95 replaced with stars AND characters 210 to 218 replaced with stars - but at the moment only second replace takes place as first one is considered to be a part of first group (due to greedy behaviour).

Comment: ARRG you rock! Works a treat.

Comment: @Konstantin > thanks, I reposted as an answer then :)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to parse, here? Because the kind of information in your example looks like the kind where regular expressions are really not the right tool and will come back to bite you in the ass later. If you're parsing JSON, just use one of the many JSON libraries and it will save you lots and lots of headaches, especially when you start dealing with things escaped backslashes and chance reordering of key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern

```
("answer"\s*:\s*")(.*?)(")
```

Seems to do what you want. Here's the escaped version for Java:

```
(\"answer\"\\s*:\\s*\")(.*?)(\")
```

The key here is to use `(.*?)` to match the answer and not `(.*)`. The latter matches as many characters as possible, the former will stop as soon as possible.

The above pattern won't work if there are double quotes in the answer. Here's a more complex version that will allow them:

`("answer"\s*:\s*")((.*?)[^\\])?(")`

You'll have to use `$4` instead of `$3` in the replacement pattern.

Comment: This will not work properly when the value contains an escaped double-quote: `{ "answer": "\"" }`.

Comment: I think you want to replace `.` with `(?:[^\\"\r\n]|\\[^\r\n])`.  The edit won't match `{ "answer": "\\" }`.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex works for me :

```
regex = "(?<=answer\"\\s:\")(answer.*?)(?=\"})";
rep = "*****";
replaceALL(regex,rep);
```

The `\` and `"` might be incorrectly escaped since I tested without java.

http://regexr.com?303mm

Comment: This will not work properly when the value contains an escaped double-quote: { "answer": "\"" }.

Comment: `\"answer \" 5\"` instead of `\"answer 5\"` ?